# Why check self != nil in -init when messaging nil has no effect?

Tags: objective-c

Assuming our `-init` method only invokes messages on `self`, why is it common to check if `self != nil` if messaging `nil` has no effect?

Let's say we have an initializer as follows:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self doThis];
        [self setFoo:@"Bar"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Instead of checking `self`, we could write:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    [self doThis];
    [self setFoo:@"Bar"];

    return self;
}
```

Now if for some reason `[super init]` returns `nil`, there would be no difference in the outcome of the method as far as I know. Why then do we constantly perform this check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send a message to nil, but you cannot access the instance variables of nil.  You'll get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception.

Consider a class that has instance variables:

```
@implementation MyObject {
    int instanceVariable;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    instanceVariable = 7;
    return self;
}
```

What happens if `[super init]` returns nil in this example?  You will try to access that `instanceVariable` off of a null pointer and you will get an exception.

Even if you're not accessing any instance variables, other things can certainly go wrong if you don't check for `self == nil`.  You can easily leak `malloc`-allocated memory or file handles, or pass yourself to some method that's not expecting nil.

Other answers claim that you can leak objects if you don't check for nil.  For example:

```
@implementation MyObject

@synthesize someProperty; // assume it's an NSObject *

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    [self setSomeProperty:[[NSObject alloc] init]];
    return self;
}
```

This won't leak under ARC, even if `self` is nil.  Under manual reference counting (MRC), this example will leak whether `self` is nil or not, because there's nothing to balance the +1 retain count from `[NSObject alloc]`.

The proper way to do it under MRC is this:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    [self setSomeProperty:[[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease]];
}
```

or this:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    [self setSomeProperty:object];
    [object release];
    return self;
}
```

Neither of those will leak, whether `self` is nil or not.

If you bypass the setter method, like this, you'll just crash if `self` is nil:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    _someProperty = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: It's rather a signal - C doesn't have exceptions.

Comment: It's a CPU exception, not a C++ exception.  Check out `/usr/include/mach/exception_types.h`.

Comment: @rob mayoff: Thanks for elaborating on things that could possibly go wrong. Just to clarify: with the assumption that we're using ARC and only sending messages to self and not creating any objects, is there any danger in not checking for nil?

Comment: You also have avoid allocating any resources that ARC doesn't manage, like malloc memory or,file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

If [super init] did in turn return nil, then you would end up possibly allocating more objects that will never be used, since when you return self, you will return nil; So those objects will not be released.

Comment: @user1606088 Don't be discouraged though.  This is a pretty subtle issue.